# Density of primes in a polynomial

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics

Consider that $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial with integer coeficients, that $\mathrm{gcd}$ of its coefficients is $1$. What is the [natural density](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of the below set?
$$A = \{n\ |\ p(n)\ \text{is prime}\}$$

And can we say an statement like prime number theorem about $A$?

For example the density for $p(x)=x$ is zero and maybe in general case that is zero too.

Comment: The problem is that, frankly, no one knows.  If $p(x)$ is linear, then the density of $A$ is zero (and in fact, one can give $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$ estimates for the number of elements of $A$ less than $n$); this is a consequence of Dirichlet's theorem.  But as of right now, nobody knows a _single_ polynomial of degree $\gt 1$ that is known to have even infinitely many prime values, so all the heuristics about density are only that.

Answer (score 0):

we have two cases:

- $p(x)$ is a linear polynomial: in this case we have a prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions that will give the distribution of primes in them. look at [this page](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/the-prime-number-theorem-in-arithmetic-progressions-and-dueling-conspiracies/).
- degree of $p(x)$ is greater than 1: in this case approximatly the problem is open. for example we don't know that there is infinitly many prime of the form $n^2+1$ or not.